# Angular $destroy is stacking

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 controllers, one has a $destroy function for when the model is closed.

```
>  $scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
>        
>         var args = {};
>         $rootScope.$emit('refreshh', args);   
>     });
```

and in the other controller, i have

```
$rootScope.$on('refreshh', function(event, args) {
        console.log("modal closed");

    });
```

When i keep opening and closing the model it works fine, i get "modal closed", but then if i go to another page like from the nav bar (without refreshing the page) and go back to that page i will then get "modal closed" "modal closed" and if i repeat this process i will get "modal closed" "modal closed" "modal closed" as if the code is running X amount of times. What could this be?

Comment: I think that your problem is in your controller that you're declaring the `$rootScope.$on('refreshh'...` as you're registering the event in `$rootScope` even if your controller gets destroyed it'll keep the binding to `$rootScope`. Try to do `$scope.$on('refreshh'...` instead. Hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you bind an `$on` listener to `$rootScope` and you don't explicitly destroy that listener ([see docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on)), then each time your second controller is instantiated, it adds ANOTHER identical listener to `$rootScope`. In your second controller, you either need to bind to local `$scope` or be sure to destroy the listener when your second controller is destroyed.

Second controller:

```
var deregisterListener = $rootScope.$on('refreshh', function(event, args) {
  console.log("modal closed");
});


$scope.$on("destroy", function() {
  deregisterListener();
});
```

Without this, what ends up happening is that your `$rootScope` racks up a listener for each time you instantiated your second controller, resulting in all those identical listeners firing at once.